# How to use lodash's merge with a custom timestamp property

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to merge two objects together and I want the property that has the higher of the two timestamps to be the one that wins. Is this possible or should I be using a different function? Please note, this object holds user preferences and can contains an unlimited number of properties.

Here is what I am trying to merge with the desired outcome.

```
let preferences1 = {
  'favorite-color': {
    timestamp: 1,
    data: 'red'
  },
  'nickname': {
    timestamp: 1,
    data: 'dude'
  }
};

let preferences2 = {
  'favorite-color': {
    timestamp: 2,
    data: 'black'
  }
};

let outcome = {
  'favorite-color': {
    timestamp: 2,
    data: 'black'
  },
  'nickname': {
    timestamp: 1,
    data: 'dude'
  }
};

const result = merge({}, preferences1, preferences2);
```

Comment: Check the timestamps and let that determine the argument order of the merge function call.

Comment: the object is dynamic "user preferences" and contains an un-limited amount of properties.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you provide more information? What is a sample input to the merge and what is the desired output? Can you show the actual code you have so far?

Comment: please see edits. does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using lodash 4+, it looks like the [`mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#mergeWith) function would be helpful here.

```
let preferences1 = {
  'favorite-color': {
    timestamp: 1,
    data: 'red'
  },
  'nickname': {
    timestamp: 1,
    data: 'dude'
  }
};

let preferences2 = {
  'favorite-color': {
    timestamp: 2,
    data: 'black'
  }
};

let outcome = _.mergeWith({}, preferences1, preferences2, function (obj, src) {
  if (!obj || !obj.timestamp || !src.timestamp) return undefined;
  if (obj.timestamp > src.timestamp) return obj;
  return src;
});
```